# How to get last insertd id in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Get Last Created Entry's ID From Sql Database With Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315017/how-to-get-last-created-entrys-id-from-sql-database-with-asp-net)
>   [How to get last inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

I am facing difficulty to get the last inserted field in

```
selct scope identity();

SELECT *
FROM Person
ORDER BY PersonID DESC
LIMIT 1
```